# Method/product for cleaning cigarette smoke off of LCDs?

Tags: lcd, cleaning

OK, I admit I am a smoker.  Im trying to quit, its hard though...

So I have several LCD monitors that have accumulated grime from cigarette smoke over the years.  Every so often I take a soft cloth and dip it in mildly soapy water.  I gently wipe the screens down to clean them.  It works, however its an extremely slow and tedious process, as it takes many passes to get the screens clean.

Is there a better alternative out there?  Is there a home 'remedy,' or even a tested commercial product?

Comment: The best solution I have ever used for cleaning my LCD is baby wipes. I have cleaned crayon, colored pencil, food and liquid of all types, etc that my kids have left on my screen. I'll admit I have not tested them on smoke residue, but if they can get crayon off with ease, smoke residue shouldn't be that bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use an equal ratio of distilled water and vinegar or isopropyl (rubbing) alcohol.  Be sure to use a microfiber cloth or anything non-abrasive.  As a general rule of thumb, you don't want liquid to drop/drip on the monitor as it can get inside and destroy it.  Just apply a small amount to your cloth.

Comment: I thought alcohol on LCD screens was a no-no.

Comment: It depends on the coating used on the lcd screen itself and you are correct some manufactures, including Apple, warn against it as it can damage the outer coating.  I have used it on Dell branded lcd screens with no problem, but keep in mind, I am using a 50-50 ratio of water and alcohol.  The safest method is vinegar if you are concerned and/or are unsure of the manufacturer warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I am not smoker, but I use some cleaning liquid for LCDs which was shipped with some microfiber cloth. I use product called "D​-Clean Premiu​m Notebo​ok Clean ​- Crysta​l Shine", but we also have something similar by Belkin (these do not contain alcohol). I think it could be also effective for the smoke particles. The set of 20 ml cleaning solution in spray with microfiber cloth costs approx. about 8 USD in my country :-)